# Ads are not working in WP app

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing a WP 8/8.1 app. The problem that I am facing is that when I use the "Adcontrol" tool then it displays a blue line under it and it gives me the following error.

```
Error    1    The name "AdControl" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI".    C:\Users\PraneetSah\Documents\app_3\AppStudio.UI\Views\MainPage.xaml    45    11    AppStudio.UI
Error    2    The type or namespace name 'Advertising' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\PraneetSah\Documents\app_3\AppStudio.UI\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    5    17    AppStudio.UI
Warning    3    The referenced component 'Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile' could not be found.     AppStudio.UI
Warning    4    The referenced component 'Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI' could not be found.     AppStudio.UI
Error    5    The type 'ads:AdControl' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.    C:\Users\PraneetSah\Documents\app_3\AppStudio.UI\Views\MainPage.xaml    45    12    AppStudio.UI
```

Just is case; My SDK/Studios are all installed in their default location but the project I am currently working on is not in default locaiton and is present in Documents{custom-folder\ ...So maybe this could be problem? or something else? Please help me out. Following is the code for adcontrol that I am using(please note that it shows blue line below
ads:AdControl":

```
<ads:AdControl Width="480" Height="80"
                  ApplicationId="XXXXXX" AdUnitId="XXXXXX"
                  IsAutoCollapseEnabled="True"
                  IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: You have the "ads" referenced on the root, but did you add the reference to the correct project?  Expand References, make sure there isn't an error, or remove and re-add to be safe anyways.

Comment: YAY! got it working! dude you deserve massive respect! Correct answer...It worked by just remving and re-adding...BTW I have done it in past, but it didn't worked..but this time..magic happened and it worked ...thanks a lot dude!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ads namespace to the xaml.
This should be covered by Microsoft examples source code, please take a look at them.